# How do I get the name from a magnet URI using regex?

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

How do I get the name of a torrent from a magnet link using regex? The URI looks like this:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:1e4dae83371ba704d5d89e1828068ef0c4151e32&dn=Steam+OS+Official+Installer&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337
```

I thought `&dn*&` would work but it gets it to the last &, when I only want the one after the dn.

I want everything from `'&dn=` to the next `&`, but I can't get the pattern right, can anybody offer me some insight on the best way to do this and explain each part of the pattern? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lazy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (by adding `?` to the group construct):

```
&dn=(.*?)&
```

Which simply means, a match will end on first `&`, opposite to the default greedy matching when it will try to match as much as possible.